# Defining a variable as a copy of another one with a condition

Tags: python, numpy, variables

I have a variable `a`, that's an array, and I want to define another variable `b`, which is the copy of `a`, except for a condition (let's say, every non-zero element should be set to 1). I can write this in the following way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([2, 7, -2, 0, 0, 9])
>>> b = np.where(a != 0, 1, 0)
>>> print(b)
>>> array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

That's about fine, but I think I have encountered before the use of a simpler python notation, using no `numpy`, that allowed for defining `b` as a copy of `a`, but with a condition, all in one line of code, containing two equality signs, it was something like this:

```
b = a[a!=0]=1
```

The above doesn't work, but I hope you can help me find the code that I refer to or some other kind of simplification

Comment: `b = np.where(a != 0, 1, a)`?

Comment: @mozway That's not what I am looking for. My line `b = np.where(a != 0, 1, 0)` does the job, but I want something without numpy, something similar to a list comprehension, and I think I saw it as having 2 equality signs in one line

Comment: Does numpy factor in here? could you be thinking of list slice assignment?

Comment: [i if i == 1 else 0 for i in x] (without numpy and just using list comprehsion)

Comment: Your syntax kind of works if you're using pandas. But if you use pandas it modifies in place.

Comment: @EricYang Thanks, maybe I have seen some pandas code before and I haven't noticed. Can you give a very simple working code as an answer to my question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EricYang And actually your list comprehention should be `[1 if i !=0 else 0 for i in map_cat_gaia0]`, but anyways it helped me out to get an alternative solution :)

Comment: A list comprehension will be much slower than native numpy code. `b = a[a!=0]=1` is equivalent to `b = 1 ; a[a!=0] = 1` so `b` will necessarily be `1`

Comment: if you specify a dataframe like df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5]}), df[df['x'] == 2] = 4 will do the replacement

Comment: in your numpy code  a[a!=0]=1 modifies a in place.

Comment: Maybe `b = a.copy()` followed by `b[b!=1] = 0`

Comment: If you're using numpy arrays then why not use the `np.where` solution that you already have?

Comment: Just to note, `b` isn't really a *copy* of `a`, just a new object initialized *using* `a`. Whether you start by copying `a` or not is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

In newer Python versions we can use the `:=` walrus operator to combine the copy and the modification into one statement:

```
In [837]: a = np.array([2, 7, -2, 0, 0, 9])

In [838]: (b:=a.copy())[a!=0]=1

In [839]: b
Out[839]: array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Looks like it's a bit faster than the `np.where`

```
In [844]: timeit np.where(a!=0, 1,0)
12.3 µs ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [845]: timeit (b:=a.copy())[a!=0]=1
8.64 µs ± 257 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

But for this small array, list comprehension is faster (but scales worse)

```
In [847]: timeit [1 if i!=0 else 0 for i in a]
3.41 µs ± 15.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Even better if run on `a.tolist()`.

Making the result list an array is still a bit faster:

```
In [848]: timeit np.array([1 if i!=0 else 0 for i in a])
6.92 µs ± 56.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

`list(map())` isn't better than the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

To make a copy of an array where every non-zero element is replaced by 1 and without using numpy, you just have to iterate over the array and apply a ternary operator, where you will define the condition and the output:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 7, -2, 0, 0, 9])
b = [1 if i != 0 else 0 for i in a] # if not zero -> 1; else -> 0
```

Note that b is now a "list" not a numpy.array object.

You could also achieve it by using map and lambda:

```
b = list(map(lambda number: 1 if number != 0 else 0, a))
```